# joins two dataframes without the same keys but with a column with matching information

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, merge, key

I would like to create a new dataframe df3 from two others (df1 and df2) that have no common key but a common name field.

df1 :

```
key1    start_df2   end_df1   name                                                                                              
info1    0          101       paul       
info2    640        700       paul        
info3    700        801       pierre
```

df2 :

```
key2 name              start_df2   end_df2                                                                                              
0    paul               635         962    
1    pierre             941         1318    
2    jacques            102         587
```

Expected results, with this condition : if start_df1 > start_df2 & end_df1 < end_df2, so info1 for paul in df1 can't be listed in df3, but info2 & info3 for paul is OK.

df3

```
key? name             start_df2   end_df2 start_df1  end_df1 key1                                                                                             
?    paul             635         962     640        700     info2  
?    paul             635         962     700        801     info3 
?    pierre           941         1318    NA         NA          NA
```

....

The goal is to create df3 (merge ?) but I can't create without a common key column between df1 and df2.

So I first tried .copy :

```
df3 = df2[['contig', 'start_contig', 'end_contig']].copy()
```

but then I can't get information from df1.

Moreover, creating a third table is resource consuming, there may be a faster way.

I tried this code with 3 nested loops,but it really takes too much time :

```
nbExpected = 0
        for k, v in df2['name'].items() :
            for row in df1.groupby(['name']):
                # print(type(row))
                # print(row[1].index)
                for var in enumerate(row[1].index):
                    # print(var[1])
                    # print(df1.loc[var[1], 'start_df1'])
                    nbExpected += len(df1[(df2['name'] == v) \
                        & (df1.loc[var[1], 'start_df1'] > (df2.loc[k,'start_df2'])) \
                        & (df1.loc[var[1], 'end_df1'] < (df2.loc[k,'end_df2']))
                            ] )
        print('nbExpected', nbExpected)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please use proper code formatting as your question is hardly readable and provide a small data sample, not just past all your code.

Comment: Thank you MichaelJanz for your prompt response and advice. Here is a rewording